# display linked list recursively in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to display data in linked list recursively but I'm  not sure if my problem is in recursive function or I didn't end my list with 0.

here is my recursive function:

```
void ReverseDisplay(Node *head){ // call by Display function
cout << left; 
if (head == 0) return;

head = head->next ; // go to the next node
ReverseDisplay(head);
cout << setw(15) << head->ID << setw(15) << head->Num_hour << setw(15) << head->hourlyRate << endl;
```

}

and this is my reading

```
void ReadList(Node *&head){

int id , numHour;
float hourRate;
ifstream inFile("employee.txt");
if(!inFile){cout << " Error: opening file fail... \n\n"; return;}

inFile >> id >> numHour >> hourRate;
while(inFile){

    // create node & fill it
    Node *Employee = new Node ;
    Employee->ID = id;
    Employee->Num_hour = numHour;
    Employee->hourlyRate = hourRate;
    Employee->next = 0;

    AddNode(head, Employee); // function that caver the 4 cases

inFile >> id >> numHour >> hourRate;

}// outer while

inFile.close();
```

}

and the AddNade function is:

```
void AddNode(Node *&head, Node *Employee){

if ( (head == 0) || (head->ID > Employee->ID) ){

        Employee->next = head ;     
        head = Employee;
    }
    else {

        Node *travel = head , *trail = 0;
        while ( (travel != 0) && (travel->ID < Employee->ID )){
            trail = travel;
            travel = travel->next;

        } // end while
    Employee->next = travel;
    trail->next = Employee;


    } // end else
```

}

if some one can help me I'll be thankful...

Comment: I recommend using an iterative loop for traversing linked lists.  A recursive loop will place a lot of stuff on the "stack" for each recursive call.  In general, the capacity of the stack is less than other memory.  An iterative approach uses much less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReverseDisplay()` loose (don't display) the first node (if I'm not wrong); I propose something like

```
void ReverseDisplay(Node *head){ // call by Display function
   cout << left;
   if ( head ) {
       ReverseDisplay(head->next);
       cout << setw(15) << head->ID << setw(15) << head->Num_hour << setw(15) << head->hourlyRate << endl;
   }
```

----- **EDIT** -----

What's wrong in the current version?

Simple.

When you go to the next node

```
head = head->next ; // go to the next node
```

you loose the original `head` value and you can't display it.

It can be displayed from the calling iteration of `ReverseDiplay()`, but if you're in the first iteration of `ReverseDisplay()`, the `head` isn't displayed.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me what is wrong with my code please

Comment: Edited my answer; hoping this helps.